# I want to add a html5 slider to a webside instead of a flash slider that i have on my website

Tags: html, insert, slider

I want to add a html5 slider to a webside instead of a flash slider that i have on my website but when  i insert the html5 slider it does not show on the website i want to specific that the website was not created by me

link download website 
http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/TOkalFb5/file.html

What i want to do is to put the slider that is in slider.html in index.html  instead of that slider with that bmw picture

Please i'm disperated i want to tell that i dont know very well webprograming

Comment: It's better if you post your sample code that you have tried in the Question rather than a link in case the link expires later.

Comment: i was thinking that it would be more easy if i put the hole script

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to do some reading, make an effort and return when you have a very specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some errors in your page.
First of all the scripts order :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<meta name="keywords" content="Slider, Hi Slider, Simple HTML5 Slideshow, Free js slider" />
<meta name="description" content="Slider created with Hi Slider which enable you to publish responsive jQuery image slideshows, seamless WordPress slider plugins, amazing website sliding banners and fancy JavaScript slideshow presentation" />     

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/grid_24.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/superfish.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/tms.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sliderengine/jquery.hislider.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'> <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://www.theie6countdown.com/images/upgrade.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>  
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

And next, you need a height in pixel on this line :

```
<!----begin------Insert to your webpage where you want to display the slider-->
        <div id='hislider1' style="max-width:960px; max-height:360px; height:500px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

And be careful, you replace your metadata by the slider's one.

Here your files with the correct syntax : http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/DnLpAt9O/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand what you asked for, but if you want html5 slider please take a look at Bxslider - http://bxslider.com

You can create something similar to your slider.